# Маппинг запросов в SpringBoot 2+

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-boot, thymeleaf

В проекте (SpringBoot 2+, thymeleaf) есть простой рест-контролер вида:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@GetMapping ("/index")
public String index() {
    return "Hellow";
}
```

Если запустить в таком виде, то запрос на `localhost:8080/index` обрабатываются нормально, все что кроме этого адреса не проходит (например `localhost:8080/index/` - отдаст 404). Но если навесить аннотацию на класс:

```
@RestController ("/index")
public class Controller {

@GetMapping
public String index() {
    return "Hellow";
}
```

то запросы обрабатываются некорректно - на все запросы, `localhost:8080/index/`, `localhost:8080/`, даже мусорные адреса на которых нет маппинга - `localhost:8080/qqqqqq`) - возвращают вместо 404 - "Hellow".

Почему? Почему во втором случае все запросы к приложению поступают к этому контроллеру, хотя я задал маппинг на конкретный контекст ("/index")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что маппинг ставится не на @RestController, а на @RequestMapping или ему подобных(@GetMapping, @PostMapping...)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ содержится вот тут
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller и тут https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html. Если коротко - в скобках для @RestController () указывается имя логического компонента, а не url-паттерн.